# Angularjs using $inject doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I started a huge change in my AngularJs code to improve it. I was looking [this reference](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) and found it pretty interesting, so i was changing my code to follow thos guides.

When i got to the rout configuration i couldn't make it work.
If i use a `.config` like the code below, everything works fine.

```
angular
.module('agApp')
.config(
['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', 
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.when("/", "/First");
    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/First");
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/First");

    $stateProvider
        .state('first', {
            url: "/First",
            views: {
                "main": {
                    templateUrl: "app/component/first.html",
                    controller: 'FirstController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('second', {
            url: "/Second",
            views: {
                "main": {
                    controller: 'SecondController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    templateUrl: "app/component/second.html"
                }
            }
        })
}]);
```

But when i try to use the code as recomended on the guide, like this:

```
angular
.module('agApp')
.config('ConfigRouter', ConfigRouter);

/* @ngInject */
function ConfigRouter($locationProvider,$stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.when("/", "/First");
    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/First");
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/First");

    $stateProvider
        .state('first', {
            url: "/First",
            views: {
                "main": {
                    templateUrl: "app/component/first.html",
                    controller: 'FirstController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('second', {
            url: "/Second",
            views: {
                "main": {
                    controller: 'SecondController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    templateUrl: "app/component/second.html"
                }
            }
        })
}
```

Then it stops working and i keep getting this error:

> Failed to instantiate module agApp due to: Error: [ng:areq] 
>   Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

I toke care of the proper injection (at least, I think I did) because the output minified code looks like this:

```
function ConfigRouter(a,b,c){c.when( [.... rest of the code...]  ),ConfigRouter.$inject=["$locationProvider","$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider"],
```

On the uglify process I'm using `ngAnnotate` in this order: `concat`, `ngAnnotate` and finaly `uglify`

Am I missing something here? What may be happening to my code? 
Do I need any extra file to enable `$inject`?

I'm trying to structure my AngularJs this way for the first time. By the way, the functionality of the controllers is not affect (also because there is no injection, just a simple function and name definitions), when i can run the app, the rest is working, the problem starts when I try to use the $inject.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says it all: you're providing a string as an argument while it should be a function. That's because `config` blocks don't have names. It has to be

```
angular
.module('agApp')
.config(ConfigRouter);
```

Comment: Ok, i was trying like this because of the way the controllers work, which is the syntax i used in the config. But I'll try this. Thanks